# .htaccess redirectmatch 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I want to redirect as follows using .htaccess redirectmatch 301 rule.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/user.php?id="user_id" /user/
```

I don't want query string to be appended in redirected URL.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QueryString is not part of match in RedirectMatch directive.

To match against querystrings you need to use mod_rewrite :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=userId$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^user\.php$ /user? [L,R=301]
```

Empty question mark at the end of the target url is important, as it discards the orignal querystrings from url.

Comment: not redirecting using your method
<pre>user.php?user=1&id=74 to /user/</pre>

only redirectmatch 301 is working but it appending query string at last